# Given a solution to a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, find a solution mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Given the solution of a diophantine polynomial $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, we can use Hensel's lemma to extend this to a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and the natural homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Q}_p$ gives a solution in $p-$ adics. I heard it mentioned that we can go the other way, and I see how we can get a solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$ from a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ using the direct limit construction, but I can't figure out how to get from $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or to $\mathbb{F}_p$.

References or hints are appreciated!

Comment: You can't go from $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in general because $p$-adic numbers are a superset of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: At least $\mathbb{Z}_p$ was used properly as the set of $p$-adic integers and not $\mathbb{F}_p$. +1

Comment: Perhaps you meant homogeneous polynomials

Comment: @reuns I didn't know that this additional hypothesis was needed. Do you have a reference for the contruction for homogeneous polynomials, or is this somehow obvious?

Comment: For anyone searching this answer in the future, it was obvious: $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ so clearing denominators gives a solution.

Comment: Clearing denominators does not have to give a solution mod $p$. The equation $px-1=0$ has a solution in $\mathbf Q_p$ and there are no denominators to clear, but it has no solution in $\mathbf F_p$.